# Load RSS data into global variable

Tags: javascript, google-api, rss, global-variables

I use Javascript. I want to get RSS data by API google (this link: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/googleajaxfeed.shtml ), then insert the data into a Array (*Global variable*). But my global variable can not save data.

Inside **rssfeedsetup()** function, ARR_DATA (*Global Array*) have data. However, after load **rssfeedsetup()** function, ARR_DATA have no data.

Please show me, how to insert data to global variable in this case.

My code: 
Head:

```
<head>
    <title>TEST API FEED RSS</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("feeds", "1"); //Load Google Ajax Feed API (version 1)
    </script>
</head>
```

Body:

```
<body>
    <div id="feeddiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var ARR_DATA = []; // **I want to insert data into this array**

        var feedurl = "http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot";
        var feedlimit = 4;

        function rssfeedsetup() {
            var feedpointer = new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl); //Google Feed API method
            feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit); //Google Feed API method
            feedpointer.load(displayfeed); //Google Feed API method
        }

        function displayfeed(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                var thefeeds = result.feed.entries;
                var arr_Temporary = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < thefeeds.length; i++) {

                    arr_Temporary[0] = thefeeds[i].title;
                    arr_Temporary[1] = thefeeds[i].link;

                    // insert RSS data into ARR_DATA.
                    ARR_DATA.push(arr_Temporary);

                    console.log('value before:', ARR_DATA); // check value of ARR_DATA, there have data exist.
                }
            } 
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            rssfeedsetup(); // call function

            console.log('value2 after:', ARR_DATA);  // check value of ARR_DATA, there is no data.
        };
        console.log('value2 after:', ARR_DATA); //check value of ARR_DATA, there is no data.
    </script>
</body>
```

I have got value console:
[image of firebug on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYw16.jpg)

Ps: Why ARR_DATA no contain data after load function rssfeedsetup()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push data into the array like this:

```
function displayfeed(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                var thefeeds = result.feed.entries;

                for (var i = 0; i < thefeeds.length; i++) {
                    var feed = { 
                        title: thefeeds[i].title,
                        link: thefeeds[i].link
                    };

                    ARR_DATA.push(feed);
                }
                console.log(feed);
            } 
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you, after load feedrsssetup() function, ARR_DATA still have no data.

Comment: You are probably trying to use the feed module prior to it be loaded. If you follow the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide  you'll see that instead of call rssfeedsetup() function in windows.load, you should do it after you require the rss module, using this code:  google.load("feeds", "1"); google.setOnLoadCallback(rssfeedsetup);

Comment: Yeah, GREAT IDEA! Thank you for GREAT IDEA! I click to accept your answer was the most helpful in finding my solution.

Comment: In my project, I solved it by another way. I called rssfeedsetup() in page loading. Not in windown.onload. Thank you again!

Comment: @vkting do you mean using document.onload?

Comment: I do not know what the difference between "window.onload" and "document.onload". Can you please tell me about it?

Comment: document.onload is fired first, when the DOM is ready, window.onload is fired later, when all elements of the window are loaded (images, scripts, etc)

Comment: Thank for the explanation. I think I got it. I called rssfeedsetup() before window.onload happen. Then I get data inside function window.onload = function () {...getData...}. Finally, I did it. ARR_DATA saved data, and i can used the data.